# Global symbol "$fh" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $fh"?)

Tags: perl

1. I glob the files in a directory (non-recursive) that have an extension of .srt, .ass, .ssa, .txt with:

   ```
   my @subfiles = glob '*.srt *.txt *.ass *.ssa';
   ```
2. Then, to write the xml sub files for spumux I call:
   `WRITESUBXML();` which is as follows:

   ```
   sub WRITESUBXML {
       foreach my $i (@subfiles) {
           $SUBXMl="/users/dragonzero29/.wine/drive_c/mvtmp/$subfiles[$i].xml";
           open(my $fh, '>', $SUBXMl) or die "Could not open file $SUBXMl $!";
           print $fh "<subpictures format=\"NTSC\">\n";
           print $fh "<stream>\n";
           print $fh "<textsub filename=\"$subfiles[$i]\"\n";
           print $fh "characterset=\"UTF-8\"\n";
           print $fh "fontsize=\"28.0\"\n";
           print $fh "font=\"/users/dragonzero29/.wine/drive_c/mvtmp/arial.ttf\"\n";
           print $fh "fill-color=\"yellow\"\n";
           print $fh "outline-color=\"LightGray\"\n";
           print $fh "outline-thickness=\"2.0\"\n";
           print $fh "horizontal-alignment=\"center\"\n";
           print $fh "vertical-alignment=\"bottom\"\n";
           print $fh "left-margin=\"60\"\n";
           print $fh "right-margin=\"60\"\n";
           print $fh "top-margin=\"20\"\n";
           print $fh "bottom-margin=\"30\"\n";
           print $fh "subtitle-fps=\"29.97\"\n";
           print $fh "movie-fps=\"29.97\"\n"; 
           print $fh "movie-width=\"720\"\n";
           print $fh "movie-height=\"480\"\n";
           print $fh "force=\"no\"/>\n";
           print $fh "</stream>\n";
           print $fh "</subpictures>";
           close($fh);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Then, later I call the function to write the final dvdauthor file with 
   `WRITEAUTHORXML();` which contains:

   ```
   sub WRITEAUTHORXML {
       $AUTHORFILe="/users/dragonzero29/.wine/drive_c/mvtmp/authormovie.xml";
       open(my $fh, '>', $AUTHORFILe) or die "Could not open file $AUTHORFILe $!";
       print $fh "<dvdauthor dest=\"/users/dragonzero29/.wine/drive_c/mvtmp/DVD\">\n";
       print $fh "<vmgm />\n";
       print $fh "<titleset>\n";
       print $fh "<menus>\n";
       print $fh "<pgc>\n";
       print $fh "<button> jump title 1\; </button>\n";
       print $fh "<vob file=\"/users/dragonzero29/.wine/drive_c/mvtmp/menu.mpg\" pause=\"inf\"/>\n";
       print $fh "</pgc>\n";
       print $fh "</menus>\n";
       print $fh "<titles>\n";
       foreach my $LANg = grep(/^EN/ || /^ES/,@subfiles) {
           print $fh "<subpicture lang=\"$LANg\"\n";
       }
       print $fh "<pgc>\n";
       print $fh "<vob file=\"/users/dragonzero29/.wine/drive_c/mvtmp/$MOVIe.MUXED.MPG\" 
       print $fh "<post>\n";
       print $fh "call menu\;\n";
       print $fh "</post>\n";
       print $fh "</pgc>\n";
       print $fh "</titles>\n";
       print $fh "</titleset>\n";
       print $fh "</dvdauthor>\n";
       close($fh);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

and when run it spits out:

```
syntax error at /users/dragonzero29/cm2dvd_v2.pl line 309, near "$LANg ="
Global symbol "$fh" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $fh"?) at /users/dragonzero29/cm2dvd_v2.pl line 312.
Global symbol "$fh" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $fh"?) at /users/dragonzero29/cm2dvd_v2.pl line 313.
Global symbol "$fh" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $fh"?) at /users/dragonzero29/cm2dvd_v2.pl line 314.
Global symbol "$fh" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $fh"?) at /users/dragonzero29/cm2dvd_v2.pl line 315.
Global symbol "$fh" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $fh"?) at /users/dragonzero29/cm2dvd_v2.pl line 316.
Global symbol "$fh" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $fh"?) at /users/dragonzero29/cm2dvd_v2.pl line 317.
Global symbol "$fh" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $fh"?) at /users/dragonzero29/cm2dvd_v2.pl line 318.
Global symbol "$fh" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $fh"?) at /users/dragonzero29/cm2dvd_v2.pl line 319.
Global symbol "$fh" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $fh"?) at /users/dragonzero29/cm2dvd_v2.pl line 320.
Global symbol "$fh" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $fh"?) at /users/dragonzero29/cm2dvd_v2.pl line 321.
syntax error at /users/dragonzero29/cm2dvd_v2.pl line 323, near "}"
/users/dragonzero29/cm2dvd_v2.pl has too many errors.
```

well the edits let me successfully compile the script and my dvd project script works all the way to iso creation but I notice the subtitle xml files were NOT even created so the final dvd has no subs...aargh :( pls help. Also here is the code used to generate the xml files, used with the above code

```
foreach my $i(0 .. $#subxmlfiles) {
system("spumux -s0 -m dvd -P 
\"/users/dragonzero29/.wine/drive_c/mvtmp/$subxmlfiles[$i]\" < 
\"/users/dragonzero29/.wine/drive_c/mvtmp/$MOVIe.MUXED.MPG\" > 
\"/users/dragonzero29/.wine/drive_c/mvtmp/$MOVIe.MUXED.MPG\"\n\n");
}
```

sorry for the mess I still don't understand how to put code from TextMate
into this space pls advise..

Comment: Please edit your question to properly format it, its current state makes it hard to read and impossible to know which one is line `309` as reported from your error message.

Comment: I fixed your formatting, please examine the input markdown (use the [edit] link) to see what I did for future reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perl: Global Symbol Requires Explicit Package Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366285/perl-global-symbol-requires-explicit-package-name)

Comment: Also for future reference ***ALWAYS*** Google the error message before posting here.

Comment: Your code will not compile. The line `print $fh "<vob file=\"/users/dragonzero29/.wine/drive_c/mvtmp/$MOVIe.MUXED.MPG\" ` doesn't have a closing quote or a semicolon. Please make sure to post the *exact* code that you are running,  and consider using *here documents*, `sprintf`, and alternative delimiters for `qq{}`.

Comment: Always fix the earliest error first. In this case: `syntax error at /users/dragonzero29/cm2dvd_v2.pl line 309, near "$LANg ="`

Answer (score 3):

If there is a syntax error, ignore all the other errors and deal with the syntax error first.

Syntax errors can often confuse perl as to what scope you are in; here, it is unable to parse the bad `foreach my $LANg` but does see the `}` and thinks it ends the sub.  So everything following that doesn't have a lexical `$fh`.

Comment: I am intentionally not addressing the specific syntax error here; I wanted a useful answer for people in general who get hung up on the flood of `Global symbol` errors telling them to redirect their focus

Answer (score 2):

This part is not syntaxically correct:

```
foreach my $LANg = grep(/^EN/ || /^ES/,@subfiles) {
print $fh "<subpicture lang=\"$LANg\"\n";
}
```

You need to rewrite it at least to:

```
foreach my $LANg (grep(/^EN/ || /^ES/,@subfiles)) {
    print $fh "<subpicture lang=\"$LANg\"\n";
}
```

But I would recommend instead:

```
foreach my $lang (grep { /^(?:EN|ES)/ } @subfiles) {
    print $fh "<subpicture lang=\"$lang\"\n";
}
```

Note that it may not logically do what you hope it does, if `@subfiles` is a list of filenames, the grep will return the ones which start with `EN` or `ES` (are they named like that? and you need to take into account if the paths contain directories or not) and then return the whole file name (not just what has been matched) to be in `$lang`. So `$lang` will never be just `EN` or `ES` but a whole file name. If you need to extract only part of the name, you can look after `map`, it is often a great companion to `grep`.

And as @Borodin pointed out in comments, you have other various problems in the code, like your `$i` variable in `foreach my $i (@subfiles)` is not an index (0, 1, 2, etc.) but one element of `@subfiles` into which you are iterating with `foreach`, that is a filename, and hence `$subnames[$i]` will be a runtime error as `$i` is not an index (a numerical value).

So make sure to add `use strict; use warnings;` on top of your script and debug your syntax and then runtime errors one by one.

There are many other generic improvements you could do too.
For example, have a look at "here-documents", on https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators search for `<<EOF`.

This would allow you to replace for example:

```
print $fh "<vmgm />\n";
print $fh "<titleset>\n";
print $fh "<menus>\n";
print $fh "<pgc>\n";
```

by just:

```
print $fh <<'EOF';
<vmgm />
<titleset>
<menus>
<pgc>
EOF
```

This would simplify your code a lot, as you do not need to escape `"` there.

Further ideas:

- do not name your variable `$i` or even `$LANg`: first one is void of any semantic value, second one should be `$lang` as mixed-case will be error prone
- in the same way, name your functions in lowercase and pass the filename as a parameter instead of hardcoding it inside the functions, so that they could be reused easily with other paths
- printing XML "line by line" like this is prone to error. For example, do you know that you need to escape `&`,  `<` and `>` otherwise your XML will be invalid? Use a library to do that for you.
- look after templates, like the Template Toolkit library; this would allow to separate the code from the text (XML template) which has many benefits (including automatic escaping for the issue above).

Comment: I've down-voted your post because (again) it doesn't come close to answering the question. The variables `$i`, `$j`, and `$k` are recognised as indexes and are perfectly valid in context. In this case `$i` is a file path but is used only once, as an array index. There is much more wrong with the OP's code than you have described (it won't even compile) and offering it as a solution is disingenuous.

Comment: "*The variables $i, $j, and $k are recognised as indexes and are perfectly valid in context.*" where did I say there are invalid? I just offered the suggestion that a better name could be found, that gives more semantic value. As for the rest, I do not believe this website should be used as a generic "bad code on input" -> "code all fixed for you on output" service. I replied specifically about the error given in the question (other error => other question), and provided various ideas on how to improve other stuff. You are free to dislike my way of doing things, but thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Borodin and feel free to post a better answer if you dislike the ones that you see. I believe this to be a better way of handling the problem you see, as then everyone will see all possible answers and will be free to upvote/downvote any of them. Your comment unfortunately does not help me in any way to improve my solution (based on the "framework" I explained in previous comment), so I can not change anything but again you could provide another, better in your eyes, solution that fix all the defects you see elsewhere.

Comment: great thanks for the input now, where can I get more practice and info with:

Comment: with, as I was saying: `(?:EN|ES)` for grep?

Comment: @ armight29 this is "just" a regex, so any tutorial on regex would help, or start with https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html   I also added some more text in my answer to warn you about other problems, based on @Borodin comments above.

Comment: Thanks @Ikegami I have edited to include your change on the heredoc delimiter. As for `Template`, I agree and it was already in my answer, at bottom in the list of various ideas to explore to make things simpler and better.

Comment: "if @subfiles is a list of filenames, the grep will return the ones which start with EN or ES (are they named like that?" NO, They don't start with that, they have those 2 characters between 2 dots in the filename....

Comment: @Patrick: You write *"do not name your variable $i or even $LANg: first one is void of any semantic value"* Which pretty much means you consider them "invalid".

Comment: @armight29 then `^` is a problem in your regex, it matches beginning of string...

Comment: @Borodin that will remain your interpretation then, but you are free to edit my answer I think if you want to improve that or other things. Of course, I never said they are "invalid"  I just tried to suggest it is better to have variable names that have semantic value. But if one wants to name its variable `$fjzlvoenzocke42` he is sure more than welcome to do so, and of course the variable will not be **invalid** just of poor taste...

Comment: @Patrick: I think `$i` has inherent de facto "semantic value". It has been in common use as an array index for sixty years or so, and I would be surprised if you don't use it yourself. You would certainly have a huge task to persuade programmers to stop using it, just as directing mathematicians away from *x* and *y* would be pointless. I suspect that you are claiming a point of view that you don't in fact hold, purely in defence of your answer.

Comment: @Borodin This is all fine and good, except here, in `foreach my $i (@subfiles)` , the `$i` is certainly not an index, hence the name here has poor semantic value and `$file` would have been better for example. This is all I was trying to say, sorry if the point did not get across. You were certainly misreading both my text and intent. I totally still hold that **HERE** in **THIS** construct, `$i` is poor choice but obviously I do not need to spend my energy trying to convince you as you seem biaised like each time I reply something, so I will stop here. Thank you for your comments.